# order of installation

Tags: installation

I've been trying to research the best way to approach setting up a SharePoint 2010 farm...up to the steps where i have the basic config databases and CA created but am looking towards OWA, Service Apps and CU's

Kinda wondering what the best order would be for that...

Should I have all of my service apps created on the farm first then install OWA then the CU's?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todd Klindt's recent post on [SharePoint 2010 Install Guidance](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=320) has been a most useful checklist.

Another good one to read is [Top 10 SharePoint 2010 Configuration Mistakes -- and How to Fix Them](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-misconfigurations-141636).